# How I disable the alpha, alpha numeric and special character in UITextField?

Tags: iphone

I want to disable or also I have does not give permission entering the alpha, alpha numeric and special character in UITextField I mean when user enter the alpha and special character in text box then I want to quickly message box pop-up to showing him u only have use 0, 1-9 digit. 
Please give me any source code and tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) protocol. There’s a method called `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` where you can validate the replacement string and return `NO` if it falls into one of the disallowed sets. As for the validation itself, see the method `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` of the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet:) class and the [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCharacterSet) class.

Comment: zoul,The above method is appropriate for character, but it shall works for special characters?

Comment: There’s an `invertedSet` method on `NSCharacterSet`, so that you can check if the string contains some characters from the inverted set of `decimalDigitCharacterSet`. If yes, you disallow the string. That should allow only the decimal digits (if that’s what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Call `setKeyboardType:` on your UITextField, and pass one of the `UIKeyboardType` constants. I’m not sure which one fits your description.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
}
```

Comment: Todd Yandell,
I already changing the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad in design view but then also UITextField allow me to enter alpha and special characters in text field.